# Reading Error when trying to compile SASS in vs code

Tags: css, sass, command-line-interface

I installed SASS on my machine via path ( environment variables ).
I can access help and other options(version etc.) but whenever I initiate

```
`--watch styles.scss:styles.css`
```

I get the following error :

```
`Error reading styles.scss: Cannot open file.`
```

I checked the documentation but to no avail. I get the same error when trying to get more information via

```
--trace styles.scss:styles.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason of my self-inflicted error.

When you initiate

```
--watch styles.scss styles.css
```

make sure you add the directory in case you placed your css styles in an external folder

```
--watch css/styles.scss css/styles.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thanks for your description of your self-inflicted error. It solved my problem of not seeing any output for half an hour. I had given the full path  for the input file (*path from the folder where the command runs to the input file*), but had taken that the path of the output file would be *relative to the input file* (ie: the *path from the input file to the output file*), but it should also be the full path to the output file (*path from the folder where the command runs to the output file*). In fact easier, but if one has a wrong expectation in one's head it can take a long time to realize. Your description put me on the right track!